# Determine perforce changelist number after running p4.run("sync") in Jenkins SCM pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, perforce

On the Jenkins server, Perforce plugin (P4) is installed.
Within my Jenkins server job pipeline (implemented as [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) in groovy-lang), there is a pipeline stage to sync from perforce to the jenkins workspace as:

```
p4.run("sync")
```

I want to determine the changelist number of this operation. I need to use this changelist number in the later stages of the pipeline.

I am thinking to do as follows:

```
p4.run("sync")
changelist_number = p4.run("changes -m1 #have")
```

Will this work? Or give me a better solution. Also I am very unfamiliar about this topic. It would be nice if you can explain what all this means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changelist number (that is, the highest changelist number associated with any synced revision) is returned as part of the `p4 sync` output if you're running in tagged mode:

```
C:\Perforce\test\merge>p4 changes ...
Change 226 on 2020/11/12 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 'foo'
Change 202 on 2020/10/28 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 'Populate //stream/test.'

C:\Perforce\test\merge>p4 -Ztag sync ...
... depotFile //stream/test/merge/foo.txt
... clientFile c:\Perforce\test\merge\foo.txt
... rev 2
... action updated
... fileSize 20
... totalFileSize 20
... totalFileCount 1
... change 226
```

Tagged output is converted into a dictionary that's returned by the `run` method, so you should be able to just do:

```
changelist_number = p4.run("sync")[0]["change"]
```

to sync and get the changelist number as a single operation.

There are some edge cases here -- deleted files aren't synced and so the deleted revisions won't factor into that changelist number.

A more ironclad method is to put the horse before the cart -- get the current changelist number (from the depot, not limited to what's in your client), and then sync to that exact number.  That way consistency is guaranteed; if a new changelist is submitted between the two commands, your stored changelist number still matches what you synced to.

```
changelist_number = p4.run("changes", "-m1", "-ssubmitted")[0]["change"]
p4.run("sync", "@{changelist_number}")
```

Any other client syncing to that changelist number is guaranteed to get the same set of revisions (subject to its `View`).

Comment: I forgot to mention that this code is running in a [Jenkins pipeline shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) and there is plugin installed for Perforce _(Perforce Client plugin for the Jenkins SCM provider)_. So it's actually a groovy script not python. How can I do the same in this case.

Comment: I found a example from perforce manual, `p4 changes -m 1 -s submitted`
In your answer `p4.run("changes", "-m1", "-ssubmitted")` -m1 -ssubmitted is different. Is it a typo?

Comment: Most p4 CLI flags can be either spaced out as two args or smushed together.  `-m 1` is the same as `-m1`.  I usually smush them together in code examples because it makes it easier to see what goes with what.

Comment: Can you please answer in context of p4groovy.  `p4.run("changes", "-m1", "-ssubmitted")` has a return type of `Map<String, Object>[]`. How can I extract changelist number from it?

Comment: I don't have access to a Groovy environment, but have you tried doing `.get("change")` on that Map object?

Comment: This is what I am using.        
`changelist_number = p4.run("changes", "-m1", "-ssubmitted")[0]["change"]` <next line>
        
`p4.run('sync', '@${changelist_number}')`.
         
Please update your answer.